# Footnote not working in zipped epub with library epub.js

Tags: javascript, epub, epub.js

Footnotes didn't show when book in *.epub, if it in the dir footnote is showing.

My code is below:

```
</p><a   epub:type="noteref" href="#n1">1</a></p>

<aside epub:type="footnote" id="n1">
<p>
   These have beenkjjjjjjjjj corrected in this EPUB3 edition.
   <a href="http://vk.com">VK</a>
<img src="0302.png"/>
</p>
</aside>
```

and it creates this link: `blob:http%3A//dev%3A8000/4fee7ff1-5769-42a4-b49e-bbb148f8a81d#n1`

Comment: What reader? Not all readers are going to support footnotes.

Comment: I use epub.js for rendering in web-browser and it working when epub book is unzipped.

Comment: My guess, nothing more, would be a bug/unsupported feature in epub.js.